# bundle asp.net Mvc 5 css failed

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, bundling-and-minification, asp.net-bundling

In my CSS I have

```
@keyframes slidein
{
    0%
    {
        max-height: 0;
    }
    100%
    {
        max-height: 2000rem;
    }
}
@keyframes slideout
{
    0%
    {
        max-height: 2000rem;
    }
    100%
    {
        max-height: 0;
    }
}
```

My bundle minification fails. Why?

Comment: How do you use it?

Comment: bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/static/css/bundle").Include(
                   "~/Content/static/css/styles.css"));

Comment: This code is to bundle css. View code?